# How can I conditionally require a Freeform field?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using EE5 5.3.2 and FreeForm Pro 1.8.3. I have a field where somebody selects a radio button option, then the next field is required or not based on that selection. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no built-in way to do this with Freeform for ExpressionEngine. However, nothing in Freeform is limiting you from implementing your own custom JS solution here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess Javascript and css will be your friend here...